# Prevent out of order inserts into a Postgres database

Tags: postgresql

I have a system that takes information through the web and puts that information in a postgres database. There's exactly one "kind" of information, so there's only one table. Let's model this table like this:

```
item: string
comment: jsonb
timestamp: datetime
```

There are a lot of items, and the timestamp is generated by a separate system before it gets to the web front end, which has several servers. What I need to do is guarantee that each record that is inserted into the database for a given `item` value is more recent than the last. If it is older, it should not be added to the database.

So for clarification, say there are three messages, like this:

```
Message 1:
{time: 1,
item: "A"
}
Message 2:
{time: 3,
item: "A"
}
Message 3:
{time: 2,
item: "b"
}
```

If the messages arrive in the order `1-2-3` then all three messages are put in the database, because message 3 is for a different item than message 1 or 2 and so no comparison is made.

If the messages arrive in the order `2-1-3` then message 1 is NOT placed in the database because message 2 is a more recent message for item `A`.

I'd like to use the database to make this check in order to avoid race conditions between different servers.

I've been reading through the PostgreSQL documentation and it doesn't look like I can do this with constraints or exclusions. How can I have the database make this ordering check before inserting records?

Comment: For the sake of understanding: if 2 items A, B being timestamped in the order A-B, arriving at the insertion code in the order B-A, B is to be dropped, whereas it will be kept when arriving in the order A-B ?

Comment: @collapsar wait, no. If they arrive in the order B-A, A will not be inserted into the database. If they arrive in the order A-B both will be put in the database.

Comment: Let's see if we can clarify this. You want to insert *if-and-only-if* there is not already a `message` for the `item` with a greater `time`?

Comment: @Schwern that is correct.

Comment: Can you explain (in exact technical terms) what you mean by "arrive"? At exactly which point in the process would they be considered "arrived". Do you understand what effects your decision would have on any concurrency you are hoping to benefit from (you mention "several" servers)

Comment: @RichardHuxton Several servers are, mostly, for redundancy and insuring that the external system posting messages is able to connect. By "arrive" I mean "the point at which an insert command is made to the database."

Comment: I've been trying to work out how to do this with an exclusion. However, `alter table messages add constraint only_newer_messages_for_item exclude using gist ( item with =, created_at with > ); ERROR:  operator >(timestamp without time zone,timestamp without time zone) is not commutative DETAIL:  Only commutative operators can be used in exclusion constraints.` I expect you can do something clever with timestamp ranges.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your table looks like this...

```
create table messages (
    item text not null,
    comment jsonb,
    created_at timestamp not null
);
```

You can do this with a trigger.

```
create or replace function check_only_newer_messages_for_item() returns trigger as $foo$
declare max_created_at_for_item timestamp;
begin
    max_created_at_for_item := (
        select coalesce(max(created_at), '-infinity'::timestamp)
        from messages
        where item = new.item
    );
    if max_created_at_for_item >= new.created_at then
        raise exception 'out of order message';
    end if;
    return new;
end;
$foo$ language plpgsql;

create trigger only_newer_messages_for_item
    before insert on messages
    for each row execute function check_only_newer_messages_for_item();

test=# insert into messages (item, created_at) values ('a', '2019-01-01');
INSERT 0 1
test=# insert into messages (item, created_at) values ('a', '2019-01-01');
ERROR:  out of order message
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function check_only_newer_messages_for_item() line 10 at RAISE
test=# insert into messages (item, created_at) values ('b', '2018-01-01');
INSERT 0 1
test=# insert into messages (item, created_at) values ('b', '2018-01-02');
INSERT 0 1
test=# insert into messages (item, created_at) values ('b', '2018-01-01');
ERROR:  out of order message
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function check_only_newer_messages_for_item() line 10 at RAISE
```

A composite index on `item` and `created_at` will help this perform well.